# Image transcription software

Tags: images, image-editor, transcription

Say I have an image that is handwritten. I'd like to be able to associate text to the image, maybe even line by line (like indexing). In my mind there would be two panes, one with the image and one with the transcription that the user enters.

One thought I had was to store the transcription in the metadata of an image so that the file remains image, but when opened by said software the transcription persists.

[image]
[Full example image](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3QS7-L9P7-9PCZ)

*I'm not looking for OCR software, as the images I'm hoping to associate a transcription to are handwritten and difficult to process.*